# Adding rows dynamically to table using for loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table

I want to use jQuery 1.3.2 in an html file and create a dynamic table. For this, I create the first row, then create a for loop running 10 times and in each iteration, I select the last row of the table and use `after()` to add a new row after it. This new row contains the value of the counter of my for loop.

code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 11; i += 1) {
            var newItem = $("<tr><td>"i"</td></tr>");
            $("#table1 tr:last").after(newItem.html());
        }
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
    <td>row 1 col 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, only the first row that was created in `<table></table>` is displayed. Please help out.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#table1 tr:last")
```

selects the last row. It's a bit more expensive in terms of processing needed compared to

```
$("#table1")
```

which selects just the entire table.

```
$("#table1 tr:last").after(...)
```

is expensive again, because after you selected the last row, you take one step back, get back to the parent of tr:last and try to append something.

Why not try appending table rows as children of table like this?

```
var row = $("<tr><td>"i"</td></tr>");
$("#table1").append(row);
```

Append will always add at the end of the children of table1. This should be faster. Take a look at [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i += 1) {
    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/inspired_jw/hZssN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var newItem = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>"; 
$("#table1 tr:last").after(newItem);
```